# How to properly use variables defined by `AC_DEFINE` and `AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED` in public headers?

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake

I've recently come across a library, which uses variables like `HAVE_FEATUREFOO` inside public headers.

It also includes them with statement `#include "config.h"`. These declarations are also used in struct declarations, and are conditionally removing struct members. Inconsistency of values used for library build, and build of a dependent program, will lead to memory corruption.

So, use of the library and it's headers could have following consequences:

- `#include "config.h"` fails,
- or memory corruption at runtime.

I'm very new to autotools, but after some research I've found, that they are defined using [`AC_DEFINE` or `AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Defining-Symbols.html). And, `config.h` is generated using [`AC_CONFIG_HEADERS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.66/html_node/Configuration-Headers.html).

With further research, I've found [`include_HEADERS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Headers.html), which installs headers. And, header `config.h` gets correctly installed, if it's added to the list.

Is it correct approach, to install `config.h` header file generated by autotools by `AC_CONFIG_HEADERS`?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it correct approach, to install config.h header file generated by autotools by AC_CONFIG_HEADERS?

If other *installed* headers belonging to the project depend on `config.h`, then yes, `config.h` must be installed, too.  It's the only viable approach, because the built software depends on the build-time build-system properties as memorialized in `config.h`.  You cannot, in general, count on correctly recreating that after the fact.

But installed headers **should not** `#include` an Autotools `config.h` header in the first place, nor should they rely on one indirectly.  Nor either, then, should a file named `config.h` be installed in the include file search path, or in any directory that might plausibly be expected sometimes to be added to the include path.  There is too great a risk of collisions -- of header names to some extent, but more significantly of the macro names defined and relied upon by such headers.

Bottom line: Autotools `config.h` files are for use building the project with which they are associated, not for *using* the built result.  In particular, when such a project is or includes a library, the `config.h` is unsuited for any manner of use by the library's own header files or for direct use by code wanting to call using the library.  The Autotools provide different mechanisms by which the build-time system configuration could be memorialized by customizing headers intended for installation.

---

So where does that leave you with respect to the library you're asking about?  I submit that the issue you describe is an indication of poor code quality, so that you should strongly consider finding an alternative.  There are ways that you might endeavor to fix the project, but it's unlikely to be worth your time, especially as an Autotools neophyte.

Answer (score 2):

The generated `config.h` file should never be included by user code. That means your library headers should be independent of the configure tests and you should not install `config.h`.